# API authorization using sha512, base64, UTC timestamp with Javascript/Node

Tags: node.js, authentication, axios, cryptojs

I'm trying to get access to our payment providers API but I keep getting a 403 response (forbidden). I've triple checked the credentials and they are correct. Here is the authentication instructions:

> Every request to the API must be authenticated by using the Authorization HTTP request-header.
>
> Place the timestamp in the "Timestamp" header. The value should be the time the message was created and sent in UTC.
>
> The authorization header is calculated for each request using the following formula.

```
base64 ({MerchantId}: sha512 (RequestBody + SecretWord + Timestamp))
```

> Example:

```
'Timestamp': 2016-11-16 13:21:02

'Authorization': Svea TQ1Q0MzNDJERkQxRDRDRTgxQzM2NjNGRjAwMTg3RTE3M0NDNg==
```

full documentation [Here](https://paymentadminapi.svea.com/documentation/?_gl=1*wjg39d*_ga*MTM1ODM5NzQ0Ni4xNTk0MTEyNzgz*_ga_8V99WD12F3*MTYyMTcxNDIwNy4xMy4xLjE2MjE3MTQyMTguNDk.&_ga=2.234410846.1759688786.1621429963-1358397446.1594112783#/?id=using-paymentadmin-api).

Here is the code I've got:

```
import axios from "axios";
import CryptoJS from "crypto-js";

// Below function returns the date in the following format "#YYYY#-#MM#-#DD# #hh#:#mm#:#ss#" in UTC time. 
//Code for customFormat is omitted but it returns a string in the expected for`enter code here`mat.
 
      function customDate() {
        let now = new Date();
        return now.customFormat("#YYYY#-#MM#-#DD# #hh#:#mm#:#ss#");
      }

      let timeStamp = customDate();
      let id = 123456; //Not the actual id, but same format (6 digits).
      let secret = "AaBb123C345De"; //Not the actual secret. Actual secret is a long string of digits and letters
      let body = "";

      let hashString = CryptoJS.SHA512(
        `${body}${secret}${timeStamp}`
      ).toString();

      hashString = hashString.replace(/\-/, "");

      console.log(timeStamp);

      axios
        .get(
          "https://paymentadminapi.svea.com/api/v1/orders/123",
          {
            headers: {
              "Timestamp": timeStamp,
              "Authorization": "Svea " + btoa(`${id}:${hashString}`),
            },
          }
        )
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
```

This is supposed to get a certain order number (123 in this example code) but it's not working (response 403), so can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: why would you remove "-" on the sha output ?

Comment: Not sure:). I saw it in another code snippet using sha512 so I decided to try it. Makes now difference if I keep it there or if I remove it. The problem was the timestamp. Please see my answer below. Thanks for taking the time to respond to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Simple human error. customDate return today's date in this format, `2021-05-25 08:20:02` but this is the expected format, `2021-5-25 8:20:2`. Single digits when the number is less than 10.

I replaced the customDate function with this:

```
      const now = new Date();
      const year = now.getUTCFullYear();
      const month = now.getUTCMonth() +1; // January = 0
      const day = now.getUTCDate();
      const hour = now.getUTCHours();
      const minute = now.getUTCMinutes();
      const sec = now.getUTCSeconds();

      const timeStamp = `${year}-${month}-${day} ${hour}:${minute}:${sec}`;
```

Now it works. Maybe there are better ways to get the date in a specific UTC format but this is what worked for me.